# MailMessage only accepts sender with @domain

Tags: asp.net, email, pascal, mailmessage

I wrote a code in .NET to send emails in my application:

Oxygenne + ASP.Net:

```
    mensagem:=MailMessage.Create(configemail[1],toUsers);
    mensagem.Subject:=title;
    mensagem.Body:=body;
    mensagem.IsBodyHtml:=IsBodyHtml;
```

This works fine when  configemail[1] is something like "myemail@gmail.com". However, I have the need to send emails without using domain, something like "myemail".
I am getting this error:

**The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address**

I believe this happens because the code validates if the variable has @anydomain in the string.

Am I able to override it, and let the user try to send emails without usind "@domain" in their address?

Comment: That's not C#. It looks Pascal-like. And where/how do you expect those emails to be delivered if you're not providing an email address?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have an internal SMTP server, and the users will athenticate with their usernames.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware, SMTP requires all recipient mailboxes to have a domain part. You may be able to interact with a specific mail system via other protocols that allows you to interact with just local mailboxes but you shouldn't expect *SMTP* tools to be the means of doing so.

Per [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-13):

> Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
> when domain names are used in SMTP ...  There are two exceptions to the
> rule requiring FQDNs

> The reserved mailbox name "postmaster" may be used in a RCPT
> command without domain qualification

Which in turn leads us to the syntax for the [RCPT command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.3):

> ```
> rcpt = "RCPT TO:" ( "<Postmaster@" Domain ">" / "<Postmaster>" /
> ```

```
              Forward-path ) [SP Rcpt-parameters] CRLF
```

So, the only generally applicable form that is available is the `Forward-Path`, which via a few hops (and ignoring some legacy options not helpful to you here) leads us to the `Mailbox` syntax:

> ```
> Mailbox        = Local-part "@" ( Domain / address-literal )
> ```

So, either way you have to have the `@` and then your choices boil down to a domain name or an IP address. Note that this may give us an opening though - you may be able to get what you want by specifying the addresses as `myemail@127.0.0.1`.